# power bi dynamically change measure values and names with filters

Tags: powerbi, visualization, field

I have a slicer with two values A and B(single select).

I also have two measures that countrows based on some condition, [M1] and [M2]. I need to use these measures in some visuals( a matrix/ stacked column chart etc). When filter A is applied, I need to show [M1] values only and when filter B is applied i need [M2] values only,

I was able to do this using a dax switch measure or field parameter
But the field names are not as expected in the visuals

Using switch:
M1/M2= `SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE( Table[Filtercolumn]),"A", [M1],"B", [M2], BLANK())`

In matrix visual I get the following result:

| Id | M1/M2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 20 |

Even though the values(count) is populating correctly when filters are applied the heading remains as **M1/M2**, but I need **either M1 or M2 based on filter selected**

when using field parameters:

when filter A applied

| Id | M1 | M2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 20 |  |

when filter B applied

| Id | M1 | M2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 34 |
| 2 |  | 26 |

Here the heading and values are proper but **blank columns are not required.**

Sample screenshot:

[image: Matrix visual with blank M2 values]

[image: Stacked column visual with Y axis values having both M1 and M2]

Is there any work around to get below result
when filter A applied:

| Id | M1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 20 |

when filter B is applied:

| Id | M2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 26 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `Table` to have two columns like:

| FilterColumn | LabelColumn |
| --- | --- |
| A | M1 |
| A | G1 |
| A | S1 |
| A | B1 |
| B | M2 |
| B | G2 |
| B | S2 |
| B | B2 |

Now use the LabelColumn in the Matrix visual in Columns, and use your `M1/M2` measure in Values of the Matrix. For other visuals, use the LabelColumn for Legends. That should be it.

Note: Not possible to do this with the plain Table visual. Columns will always be visible and you cannot dynamically name the columns, in the Table visual.

**Update**

If you aleady have four measure for Mx, Gx, Sx, Bx then add one more column like so:

| FilterColumn | LabelColumn | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | M1 | M |
| A | G1 | G |
| A | S1 | S |
| A | B1 | B |
| B | M2 | M |
| B | G2 | G |
| B | S2 | S |
| B | B2 | B |

Then create a new measure that looks like this:

```
Meaningful Name = SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Category]),
  "M", [M1/M2],
  "G", [G1/G2],
  "S", [S1/S2],
  "B", [B2/B2]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this.

Comment: And it didn't work? Or you are going to try it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this. But my issue is I have more fields similar to M1 and M2. For example, G1 and G2, S1 and S2, B1 and B2.                                                                When filter A is applied, M1, G1,S1 and B1 should come. and when B is applied M2,G2,S2,B2 should come. By the approach you've mentioned it will work for one such field. For column chart, when  using the LabelColumn for Legends, only one field M1/M2 can be added to the Y axis, which makes the visual worthless.

Comment: Ah.... But it still works, all you need to do is add more rows, see updated answer above. You will of course need to add more switch statements to the measure (maybe rename if to A/B)

Comment: Also see the **Update** at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: No, it will just work thanks to row context.

Comment: Thank you it is working, i added the filter column as a slicer and synced that with my existing slicer and it is working . THANKSSSS..